# How to get countries through OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS?

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap

Am able to get states information of United States by using OpenLayers Protocol.

```
new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                   version: "1.1.0",
                   srsName: "EPSG:900913",
                   url:  "http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs",
                   featureType: "states",
                   featureNS: "http://www.openplans.org/topp"
               })
```

I need to get Countries information, tried replacing the **fetureType: "countries"**, but this dint work. Can anybody help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the correct name for the layer you are trying to load. Try a getcapabilities request to the service like so:

http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?request=getcapabilities

Then search for 'countr' to find whether there are any layers with country geometries for you to use.

Edit:

I made a little JSFiddle for the layer. Depending on your connection it might take a little to load the whole of the WFS layer. In my case about 5 seconds.

Check the fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/goldrydigital/9e2xj18u/

Comment: <Name>ne:ne_10m_admin_0_countries</Name><Title>Countries</Title><Abstract>The 247 countries in the world.</Abstract>  this is not working.

Comment: please check the JSFiddle which I added to my answer. I hope you find this helpful.